# pyqgis 3 setup vector labeling not working

Tags: labeling, vector, pyqgis-3

I have a standalone pyqgis3.2.1 (Bonn) application that can display maps (vectors, rasters). I tried to setup labeling of vector layers using the following codes, but it only works for point layers, not for line layers:

```
pal_layer = QgsPalLayerSettings()
pal_layer.fieldName = 'facilityid'
pal_layer.enabled = True
labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(pal_layer)
layer.setLabeling(labels)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

I also tried setting XML properties approach like in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270994/qgis-python-custom-properties-for-labeling), but it didn't work on line vector either. What did I do wrong?

Comment: have you tried adding `pal_layer.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
` as suggested in below link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122280/labeling-line-features-using-pyqgis?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Shiko Yes, that did it. Please post it as an answer for me to accept it, and sorry I didn't see the other post, I did a search, guess it slipped my eye. But I've got to gripe a bit about this change from PyQgis 2, I really don't see why this is necessary, I mean why I don't have to do this for point? such geometry type detection can easily be done in any of the "set" method internally...

Comment: Also, I actually tried `pal_layer.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine` and it didn't work, which is a much more sensible setting than '`Line`' !

Comment: I think Above line is related to `LinePlacementFlags` and not `Placement`

Comment: if you check the source code and the API class reference you will get it  https://qgis.org/api/qgspallabeling_8h_source.html and https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#aac410504b5f2c1d09929c2beef56d26e

Comment: @Shiko Well, at the minimum, it is confusing, also, there is no need for setting Point for point layers, so why do I have to say it out loud to the setting api, it is a line this time, as the layer itself already know it is made of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `pal_layer.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line` as it seems Line feature needs placement property to be defined.

```
pal_layer = QgsPalLayerSettings()
pal_layer.fieldName = 'facilityid'
pal_layer.enabled = True
pal_layer.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(pal_layer)
layer.setLabeling(labels)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Below are the available options:

```
enum Placement
     {
       AroundPoint, 
       OverPoint, 
       Line, 
       Curved, 
       Horizontal, 
       Free, 
       OrderedPositionsAroundPoint, 
       PerimeterCurved, 
     };
```

***Enumerator***

**AroundPoint**
Arranges candidates in a circle around a point (or centroid of a polygon). Applies to point or polygon layers only.

**OverPoint**

**Line**
Arranges candidates over a point (or centroid of a polygon), or at a preset offset from the point. Applies to point or polygon layers only.

Arranges candidates parallel to a generalised line representing the feature or parallel to a polygon's perimeter. Applies to line or polygon layers only.

**Curved**  **[NA]**

**Horizontal**
Arranges candidates following the curvature of a line feature. Applies to line layers only.

Arranges horizontal candidates scattered throughout a polygon feature. Applies to polygon layers only.

**Free**
Arranges candidates scattered throughout a polygon feature. Candidates are rotated to respect the polygon's orientation. Applies to polygon layers only.

**OrderedPositionsAroundPoint**
Candidates are placed in predefined positions around a point. Preference is given to positions with greatest cartographic appeal, e.g., top right, bottom right, etc. Applies to point layers only.

**PerimeterCurved**         **[NA]**

**Reference:**
https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#a5d449d8e9cb89e5d453c6e33fe1c66cc 
https://qgis.org/api/qgspallabeling_8h_source.html

Comment: If `AboveLine` is for `LinePlacementFlags`, then naturally one would think `AbovePoint` or `OverPoint` are for `PointPlacementFlags`, not for `Placement`. Actually I am still kinda not clear what's the difference between `LinePlacementFlags` and `Placement`, it seems they are all for where to place the text label, right?

Comment: @ForComment the word line and point not related to layer type as per explanation, because the same type can be applied to different feature types